# Copy records from current day between tables on different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

As the title says, I want to copy all of the current days records from our production database to our development database. I have view access to the production database and db_owner rights to the development database. I'm writing a stored procedure that looks for the current days data, so I need to update the development data with the current days data from our production server. Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
use DatabaseProd
DECLARE @i_DateCurrent DATETIME;
SET @i_DateCurrent = CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()));
insert into DatabaseDev..dbo.Table_1
select * from dbo.TableProd
where date_received >= @i_DateCurrent
AND date_received < DATEADD(DAY,1,@i_DateCurrent)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 4
>   Could not find server 'ServerDev' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

When I check the sys.servers table, there is only one row and it is just the Production server.

I tried using sp_addlinkedserver but it gives me

> Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSaddserver_internal, Line 29
>   User does not have permission to perform this action.

So, my question is: Is there any other way to do this that doesn't require more permissions on the production server? I'd prefer a T-SQL statement since I will be doing this for awhile but if there is another way, I can do it too. The databases I'm using are both MS SQL server 2008 R2.

Comment: you have two dots: DatabaseDev..dbo.Table_1 if DatabaseDev isn't linked server try: DatabaseDev.dbo.Table_1

Comment: Seems you got those two databases on a separate servers (or instances). In this case to access databases on one server from another you will need to configure Linked Server on one of those two. MSDN - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Comment: Yes it sounds like linked server, but if you are using windows credentials and trusted connection you may also need to worry about kerberos delegation as well which might not be a road you want to go down depending on your environment.  do you use SSIS?  A pretty quick package could be created to do what you want and it would not require the 2 servers to talk but rather SSIS will do it for you.

Comment: Well, if there is not much of data one can always go and just copy+paste rows from one table into another. It might need some more effort in case of complex keys used, but I would still choose this approach over dealing with SSIS.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear. I get the linked server error when going from dev to prod. We are using windows credentials. I haven't tried SSIS but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

One the *development* server, create a linked server to the production server.  This should give you read access to everything that you need access to.

Then, do the work on the *development* server.  After all, that is a safer place to run scripts than on the production server.

Comment: Agreed that you could create a linked server on the dev box to the production box using your security credentials.  Not sure if you're using windows or sql authentication and whether you have Kerberos auth or not.  Just be aware that you can still block production if your queries take a long time.  Also be aware that cross sql server queries can take a LONG time as sometimes Sql Server just decides to copy the entire table from one server over to the other and THEN join.

Comment: I'm getting the 2nd error when I try to create the linked server from dev to prod. We use windows auth and I'm pretty sure we use Kerberos. The queries are very compact and run in just a few seconds if not faster.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the obvious SSIS, I might suggest using OPENROWSET as you appear to have persmissions to both. [MSDN OpenRowset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)